# VNC server and vnc browser client

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, vnc

I am looking to add vnc connectivity into a web application to view VM thats are on a server. I have investigated a few projects such as no-vnc and angular-noVNC for the front end frameworks. These look quite simple and easy to implement but i am concerned around the backends and how to implement. Now from what i can see people tend to be using websockify to convert the traffic over to websockets for the browser to handle.

My current arch is windows servers with Vmware hosting the Virtual machines. VNC is out of the box with VMware and i would like to make use of it to view the virtual machines

Can anyone point in the right direction to achieve a suitable backend system to allow my angular front end to connect into. I would prefer it to be open source but would consider a commercial bit of software.

I don't mind what the backend technology is used but would prefer Node or Asp.net.

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution and opted for Guacamole server, running on Ubuntu server.  The also have client which is built in JS and hence should be fairly straight forward to implement in Angular.

All information can be found: https://guacamole.incubator.apache.org/

Also found that this script was helpful to get install - Tested and confirmed working on Ubuntu 16.04:

https://www.chasewright.com/guacamole-with-mysql-on-ubuntu/

Now just need to figure out how to connect different clients with different settings, but I expect it will be fairly straightforward.